# How to extract tar (ed) Android repo?

Tags: android, linux, git, repository, tar

I'm restoring my Linux partition from backups (mostly non compressed tarballs). I'm facing a problem while extracting a tarball which is backup of synced android repo. I tared my existing repo by simple `tar -cf command` and i'm extracting it using `tar -xf blah.tar`. I'm getting the following error.

http://pastebin.com/rkyu9qvD

Dump of `tar -tvf blah.tar`

http://pastebin.com/WyrwU3v2 (truncated)

I think the problem is symlinks. For example consider failed extraction of

.repo/projects/packages/providers/DownloadProvider.git/info/exclude

If the files are extracted serially as show by -t (correct me if i'm wrong) then first it should extract `.repo/projects/packages/providers/DownloadProvider.git/info` because it is symlink (Look at dump 
`lrwxrwxrwx bootmgr/bootmgr      0 2014-03-23 11:02 .repo/projects/packages/providers/DownloadProvider.git/info -> ../../../../project-objects/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider.git/info`
) I thinks that is why it is getting error while extracting it.

Many other files are extracted wrongly in this way for ex, first it'll create `a/b/c.x` path to extract `c.x` but later founds that b is symlink to another directory and then throws error like file already exist

So any ideas how i should extract it or it is impossible.

If it is impossible then any other better way to backup existing Android repo so that i can move it to other HDD.

Answer (score 2):

From the tar documentation:

`Normally, when tar archives a symbolic link, it writes a block to the archive naming the target of the link. In that way, the tar archive is a faithful record of the file system contents. When`--dereference' (`-h') is used with`--create' (`-c'), tar archives the files symbolic links point to, instead of the links themselves.`

So try to archive with `tar -chf ...` and I guess your issues will be solved.

Comment: so there is no way to extract it :(

Comment: You can not extract something that is not archived in the tar.